# Saving Word file as Html decreases quality of equations

Tags: microsoft-word, images, html, gif

I have a Word file and I want to convert it to html. However all the equations are converted to gif and their quality becomes very low. The problem is that the system converts all that stuff in gifs. In fact when I convert the Word file into html, I get two parts: the html file complete which I can visualize and a folder which contains all the images (both pngs and gifs), a powerpoint file, an html header and some xml files. The first xml file has this structure:

```
<xml xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<o:MainFile HRef="../prova.htm"/>
<o:File HRef="item0247.xml"/>
<o:File HRef="props0248.xml"/>
<o:File HRef="themedata.thmx"/>
<o:File HRef="colorschememapping.xml"/>
<o:File HRef="image001.png"/>
<o:File HRef="image002.gif"/>
```

and it continues for all the images (image001 and image002 are the same image).

The second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a:clrMap xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"             
bg1="lt1" tx1="dk1" bg2="lt2" tx2="dk2" accent1="accent1" accent2="accent2"     
accent3="accent3" accent4="accent4" accent5="accent5" accent6="accent6" 
hlink="hlink" folHlink="folHlink"/>
```

The third:

```
<b:Sources SelectedStyle="\APA.XSL" StyleName="APA" 
xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" 
xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography">
</b:Sources>
```

And the fourth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ds:datastoreItem ds:itemID="{DE80F531-98CE-45B7-9417-C0B0EB9AEA41}"     
xmlns:ds="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/customXml">    
<ds:schemaRefs><ds:schemaRef     

ds:uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography"/>
</ds:schemaRefs></ds:datastoreItem>
```

This is the equation as png (and in fact as you can see there aren't problems)

[image]

And this is the same equation as gif

[image]

These are Word 2007 options:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- In Word, under File / Options / Advanced / Image Size and Quality,
  check "Do Not Compress Images in File" and change the default output to
  High fidelity.
- In the Save As dialog box, Tools / Web Options / Pictures, choose
  a screen size in higher quality such as 1920x1200 and set
  pixels per inch to 120 ppi.

Comment: I don't find those categories. I have Word 2007

Comment: I don't have that version any more. The first item might be found under the menu Tools / Word options. For the second one, you could post a screen capture of your Save As dialog so I can have a look.

Comment: the problem is that the options aren't in English

Comment: I don't know Italian, but maybe I can guess if you post screenshots.

Comment: I added the images

Comment: Was just going to say that this does not help: "In the Save As dialog box, Tools / Web Options / Pictures, choose a screen size in higher quality such as 1920x1200 and set pixels per inch to 120 ppi." I am looking for the solution myself currently. Unfortunately, there are only two worldwide search hits for the search term combination "rely on VML" and "low resolution", which probably narrows down the problem the most. See also here: https://superuser.com/questions/1749253/retain-hidpi-images-when-saving-a-second-time-from-word-as-web-page-html